# OBS Studio - Blank Screen problem on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: desktop-recording, obs-studio

I installed OBS Studio from Ubuntu Software Center. I get the following error:

```
It looks like you haven't added any video sources yet, so you will only be outputting a blank screen. Are you sure you want to do this?
```

Graphics card info:

```
reyansh@acer:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 8a56 (rev 07)
```

Linux distribution info:

```
reyansh@acer:~$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

I tried uncommenting `#WaylandEnable=false` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` but it didn't fix the issue.

Any kind of help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!